# combine facebook login with my user database

Tags: android, facebook

I have an app that let the user to skip the registration procedure by login using `Facebook`.

I have succeed to let the user register/login both via `Facebook` and my own mechanism but i have some problems/questions on **how do i register the user that logged in via** `Facebook`?

This is what i think :

1. I "**secretly**" register the user using its `Facebook ID` or whatever, with whatever password i want when an user login with `Facebook`.
2. Everytime an user login with `Facebook`, i will check whether the `Facebook ID` is already registered. Notice that **the password i set earlier is no use here**.
3. If the `Facebook ID` is already registered, user will be logged in using that account.
4. If not, i will perform step 1.

Do you think its the right way to do it?

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Do you need any other details about user or you need only login/pw in you db ?

Comment: @MyWay I just need some basic information like name. Thanks for replying

Comment: I don't know if this is good approach but I was doing it by this way . When user login by fb I was checking if he is already register so if the fb_id is already in my db, if not i was sending him to register form where I took additional data about him. If he was already in my db I send him to part of app for logged users. U can make fb_id column in your db and you don't need to set for them any pw. So making short assumption my approach is similar to yours, but I'm curious if sb have better idea.

Comment: I think your approach is correct. Just don't know why you need to set password for user with Facebook ID. Eventually all you need to check is whether you have it's Facebook ID stored in database, so you don't need any random generated password.

Comment: @MyWay Thanks, i think i want to avoid giving another form to user

Comment: @michal.z the problem is, the password column in my database cannot be empty/null...so im planning to insert something like "123456" for the password